# R Shiny wants to hide the global.R password

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, rpostgresql

I am writing an application in Shiny in R. Global.R is described as below to connect to PostgresSQL.

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(pool)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(max.con=10000),
  dbname = "postgres",
  host = "shiny.com...",
  user = "postgres",
  password = "passward",
  idleTimeout = 3600000
)
```

I can connect without problems, but I am reluctant to write the password directly in global.R.
Is there a good way to hide the password or write it somewhere else to read it? Thank you

Comment: perhaps have a look at https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/managing-credentials/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do so.
I assume you want an "automated" solution (i.e. no key to provide each time app is launched) therefore you may want to have a look to this SO post:
[Hide Keys in Shiny Application Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217176/hide-keys-in-shiny-application-deploy)
It basically involves an hidden file storing credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing your password to .Renviron. You can easily access .Renviron using `usethis::edit_r_environ()`.
Store it as, for example, YOURPASS = 'Password', and call it like this in your code:

```
pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(max.con=10000),
  dbname = "postgres",
  host = "shiny.com...",
  user = "postgres",
  password = Sys.getenv('YOURPASS')),
  idleTimeout = 3600000
)
```