# Pass AWS.S3 credentials to shiny-server app in EC2 instance without .Renviron

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I've built a shiny app that saves and reads data from S3, using the aws.s3 package.

Along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217176/hide-keys-in-shiny-application-deploy) I have saved my AWS credentials in a .Renviron file and successfully deployed the app to shinyapps.io

Now comes the problem. I want to host the app on an EC2 instance (I'm following this [excellent tutorial](https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/guide-shiny-aws/#)). To do that, I need to clone the app from github. But I've added .Renviron to .gitignore.

The question is: can I make a .Renviron file within the EC2 instance? Is there some other way I should be approaching this?

PS I've tried creating it with `touch .Renviron`  but shiny-server doesn't seem to have permission to access that file.

Comment: Did you restart the shiny server after creating the Renviron file? Did you get a specific error message that made you think it was a permissions issue? Does the file have the same owner as the rest of the application files?

Comment: I did restart. The reason I thought permission was that if ```cd my-app``` then ```sudo less .Renviron``` I can see my credentials. But If I assume the role of the user (shiny) with ```sudo su shiny``` then I can no longer open the .Renviron file with the same steps

Comment: >>Does the file have the same owner as the rest of the application files?
This, I don't know how to check..

Comment: Where exactly did you create the file? Just in your home directory? Is that the same place that you put the application code? You can change the owner of the file to the shiny user with `chown`

Comment: Wow - you did it! The solution was indeed ```chown```. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to MrFlick for this. Here was the final solution.

1. `cd` to the folder containing your app and create a .Renviron file using `touch .Renviron`
2. Edit the file, using `sudo nano .Renviron`

   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = yourkeyid

   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = yoursecretaccesskey

   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = yourregion
3. Change the owner of the file, in my case `chown ubuntu .Renviron`

When you've done all that, you can `Sys.getenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)` from your R code.